# Caching django cms CustomPlugin

Tags: django, caching, django-cms, django-cache

I am developing a website using DjangoCMS, fully front-end editable using CustomPlugins.

I was wondering if is there any workaround to not cache plugins that are inside specific placeholders.

Let's say I have a CustomPlugin, and I want this plugin to be cached everywhere except if it is inside a `{% static_placeholder 'special_placeholder' %}`
The `cache = False` flag in the definition of my CustomPlugin does not do what I want (I want this plugin to be cached or not depending on the placeholder it is included). The global settings `CMS_PLUGIN_CACHE` and `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CACHE` don't fit my needs because of the same.

I would be really thankful if you could give me some tips about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can control this directly inside your Plugin class

```
class YourPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
   model = YourCustomPluginModel
   render_template = 'yourapp/yourtemplate.html'

   def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
       # you can cache "your_data" depending on 'placeholder' here

       context.update({
           'instance': instance,
           'placeholder': placeholder,
           'your_data': your_data
       })
       return context
```

plugin_pool.register_plugin(YourPlugin)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the `render` method is not called if the Plugin is cached. I already set some context variables in the `render`, but as the plugin is cached are o are not stored, depending if the plugin is or isn't in cache.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLamasFuente it is not possible. you either cache the whole plugin or remove the caching and cache the context on your own inside `render`